# Iverilog include file can't find and modules are missing

Tags: compilation, verilog, iverilog

I write Makefile to compile my current project. But the including file and module in testbench can't be found.
The error information
[image]
makefile
[image]
source list
[image]

It will work if I put all the source files in the same directory. Command below
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This question has been fixed by adding +incdir

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBjBk.png)